# JQuery + Primefaces

Tags: jquery, css, jsf, primefaces

hi everybody i'm using

- jsf 2.2
- primefacs4.0
- Tomcat 7 as server
- eclipse kepler as IDE
  and i'm trying to fix my own template to work with in my dynamic web project : the problem that when i insert a  and indicat a header the header bar is too large and i can't figure out why because i'm new in web design 
  here is my css stylesheet

  body {
          margin: 0px;
          padding: 0;
          color: #f1ffb8;
      }
      /* HeaderP */
      #headerP {
          padding: 4px 0px;
          height: 75px;
          position: relative;
      }

  ```
  #logo {
      text-align: left;

  }
  #menu {
      position: absolute;
      top:25px;
      right:15px;
      padding: 0;
      height: 59px;
      overflow: hidden;

  }

  #sidebar {
      float: left;
      width: 18%;
      padding-left:2px;
      padding-right:3px;
      margin-right:-1px;
      margin-left: -1px;
      overflow: hidden;
  }


  #sidebar a.ui-state-highlight {
      border:0 none;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-weight: normal;
  }

  /* Footer */
  #footer {
      height: 70px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 0 20px;
      font-size: 14px;

  }



  #footer .copyright {
      float: left;
  }



  .ui-widget {
      font-size: 18px !important;
  }
  .ui-panel-titlebar {
      font-size: 18px !important;
      font-weight: 10% !important;
      min-width: inherit;

  }

  #contenu{
      margin-left:260px;
      margin-right: 7px;
      margin-top: 1px;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
  #contenu .header{
      border:0 none;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-weight: normal;
  }
  ```

and this is my template.xhtml

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">


<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="#{request.contextPath}/template.css" />

    <title></title>
</h:head>

<h:body  >
<div id="container">
    <div id="headerP" class="ui-widget ui-widget-header">
        <div id="logo">
            <p:graphicImage url="./eli.png" width="80" height="80" />
        </div>

        <div id="menu" class="ui-widget">
            <p:button icon="ui-icon-home" />
            <p:button icon="ui-icon-gear" />
            <p:button icon="ui-icon-power" />


        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="core" class="ui-widget">
        <div id="sidebar"
            class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-helper-clearfix ui-shadow">

                <h:form>
                    <f:ajax>
                        <p:menu style="width:235px;">

                            <p:menuitem value="Acceuil" icon="ui-icon-home" />
                            <p:submenu label="Caisse">
                                <p:menuitem value="Nouvelle Commande" icon="ui-icon-cart"
                                    url="/faces/nouvelleCmd.xhtml" />
                                <p:menuitem value="Journal" icon="ui-icon-clipboard"
                                    url="/faces/Journal.xhtml" />
                            </p:submenu>
                            <p:submenu label="Client">
                                <p:menuitem value="Ajouter un client" icon="ui-icon-contact"
                                    url="/faces/AjouterClient.xhtml" />
                                <p:menuitem value="Mes Clients" icon="ui-icon-person"
                                    url="/faces/ListClient.xhtml" />
                            </p:submenu>
                            <p:submenu label="Articles">
                                <p:menuitem value="Nouveau Articles" icon="ui-icon-pencil"
                                    url="/faces/AjouterProduit.xhtml" />
                                <p:menuitem value="Mes Articles" icon="ui-icon-star"
                                    url="/faces/ListProduit.xhtml" />
                            </p:submenu>
                            <p:submenu label="Stock">
                                <p:menuitem value="Mon Stock" icon="ui-icon-tag"
                                    url="/faces/Stock.xhtml" />
                                <p:menuitem value="Analyse et statistique "
                                    url="/faces/Analyse.xhtml" icon="ui-icon-signal" />
                            </p:submenu>
                            <p:submenu label="Magasin">
                                <p:menuitem value="Ajouter un Operateur" icon="ui-icon-contact"
                                    url="/faces/AjouterOperateur.xhtml" />
                                <p:menuitem value="Mes Personnels" icon="ui-icon-person"
                                    url="/faces/ListOperateur.xhtml" />
                            </p:submenu>
                        </p:menu>
                    </f:ajax>

                </h:form>

        </div>
        <div id="contenu" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-helper-clearfix ui-shadow ui-panel-titlebar">
                            <ui:insert name="content"></ui:insert>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer" class="ui-widget ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
        <p class="copyright">Elite-Inspire © 2014</p>
    </div>
</div>
</h:body>
</html>
```

and here is my page to insert in place of

```
 <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" template="templaate.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="content">



                <p:panel>
                    <h:form id="form">

                                <p:panel id="panel" header="Nouveau Opérateur">

                                    <p:messages id="msgs" />

                                    <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="10" id="formulaire">
                                        <h:outputLabel for="Nom" value="Nom Opérateur: " />
                                        <p:inputText id="Nom" value="#{agentBean.nomAg}"
                                            required="true" label="Nom">
                                            <f:validateLength minimum="2" />
                                        </p:inputText>
                                        <p:message for="Nom" display="icon" />

                                        <h:outputLabel for="prenom" value="Prenom Opérateur: " />
                                        <p:inputText id="prenom" value="#{agentBean.prenomAg}"
                                            label="Prenom" required="true">
                                            <f:validateLength minimum="2" />

                                        </p:inputText>
                                        <p:message for="prenom" display="icon" />

                                        <h:outputLabel for="mat" value="Matricule: *" />
                                        <p:inputText id="mat" value="#{agentBean.matriculeAg}" required="true">

                                        </p:inputText>
                                        <p:message for="mat" display="icon" />

                                        <h:outputLabel for="mdp" value="Mot de passe: *" />
                                        <p:password id="mdp" value="#{agentBean.motDePasse}"
                                             label="Password 1" required="true"  >
                                            <p:watermark value="taper votre mot de passe" for="mdp"></p:watermark>
                                        </p:password>
                                        <p:message for="mdp" display="icon" />

                                        <h:outputLabel for="tel" value="N° Téléphone: " />
                                        <p:inputText id="tel" value="#{agentBean.telephone}"
                                            label="tel" required="false">
                                            <f:validateLength minimum="8" />
                                        </p:inputText>
                                        <p:message for="tel" display="icon" />
                                        <h:outputLabel for="email" value="e-mail: " />
                                        <p:inputText id="email" value="#{agentBean.email}"
                                            label="email" required="false">
                                            <f:validateRegex
                                                pattern="[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]@[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]" />
                                        </p:inputText>
                                        <p:message for="email" display="icon" />
                                        <h:outputLabel value="Titre: " />
                                        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{agentBean.titre}">
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="--" itemValue="" />
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="simple Opérateur"
                                                itemValue="simple Opérateu" />
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="gérant magazin"
                                                itemValue="gérant magazin" />

                                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                                    </h:panelGrid>


                                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px"
                                        cellpadding="5">
                                        <p:commandButton id="btn" value="Ajouter"
                                            action="#{agentBean.ajouter}" update="panel" />
                                    </h:panelGrid>
                                </p:panel>

                    </h:form>
                </p:panel>


    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

i can't figure out why i have a large header bar in my pannel

Comment: Could you add an image and say how large the header should be? I'm expecting it to be 83px tall

Comment: @LcLK i'm so sorry i can't cause i'm new in this forum but the header has the same tall as the sidebar menu